# Special Characters (encoding issue)

Tags: php, xml, encoding

I am parsing an xml file. The XML is encoded in utf-8. When words contain special characters, they are distorted. I cannot control the xml file, but is there anything I can do on my end to properly display words?

Example

```
Shows up as: SkÃƒÂ¶vde
Should Be: Skövde OR Skovde
Shows up as: KaposvÃƒÂ¡ri RÃƒÂ¡kÃƒÂ³czi
Should be: Kaposvári Rákócz  OR Kaspovari Rakocz
```

Is there anything I can do to convert the first, to the second through php? There are many other cases, these are just too i found really quick.

edit: I'm not sure of the coloring issues. They don't mean anything.
edit 2: The xml already contains the words in the "Show up" state I wrote. It's not that I'm reading them wrong. The xml shows SkÃƒÂ¶vde, and I read SkÃƒÂ¶vde. It should really be Skövde. Now I need on my end to convert it to what it should be.

Comment: Can you provide the script that parses xml? And where you try to output it.

Comment: where did you see that output?? in a database, on a website in your browser, in an other file you have written? please post your sample code..

Comment: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/), [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: What code is related to this? By showing only the output and anything further this looks like a double-encoding of UTF-8 as Latin-X as UTF-8 as Latin-X. So basically said: You do it wrong. Because you do not show *what* you do, we can only answer: Do it right and the problem disappears.

Comment: When I access the xml file through the browser (or save and open in notepad++), it has utf-8. When I go through and visually see the file, I see exactly what I posted that it shows up as. When I read the string, it is already in this "Show up" state. Now I need to convert this string to what I need it to output as.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are reading the XML correctly (i.e. you get utf-8 strings out of the XML document), however you are not displaying them correctly.

You are displaying utf-8 strings in a page that's not in utf-8.

You have to either convert the strings before displaying them:

(Assuming the encoding of your page is iso-8859-1; if you don't know, look at page informations in your browser)

```
mb_convert_encoding($str, "iso-8859-1", "utf-8");
```

Or set the charset of the page to utf-8:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

// or (in html) :

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

Comment: I edited the question with more details from comments.